# Zenity checklist from file

Tags: shell-script, zenity

I created a checklist and I want to insert data from a file in a specific order.

[image]

The data comes from a terminal command in my bash script:

```
data=$(lsblk -o name,size,model --nodeps >> /data.txt
```

This is the content of the file:

[image]

How can I match the checklist with the content of the .txt file?
I tried something like `cat data.txt | tr "something"` but it didn't work according to my needs. This is the output I get, when combined:

[image]
Thank you for your time!!

Comment: "_How can I match the checklist with the content of the .txt file?_" the [documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/list.html.en) clearly explains that you get the first column value(s) back for the selected item(s). What's the problem?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the output I actually get from the script. I will edit it in a second.

Comment: You don't seem to show the result from running `zenity`, which is where the matches are sent. For example `matches=( $(zenity...) ); echo "${matches[@]}"`

Comment: Okay so how do I need to change my code?

Comment: Share a small working-as-best-you-can example (as text, not as a screenshot) and I'll make suggestions